# how to compile c++ in Solaris using cc?

Tags: c++, solaris

I wrote a program, which needs to be tested in **Linux**, **Windows** and **Solaris**. The first two were easy, but Solaris has been very troublesome. I don't have g++ in the Solaris machine I'm running those tests, so I'm stuck with `cc`.
So, I first tried:

```
cc -g -o transfer transfer.cpp -lcurl
```

and the output was:

```
ld: fatal: file transfer.cpp : unknown file type
ld: fatal: no output written to transfer
```

If someone knows any other native `C++` compiler for `Solaris`, please let me know, and I will give it shot. I went to Oracle Solaris website, and they said they support `.cpp` files in `cc`. Could someone please help me with that?
Thanks

Comment: I _think_ the C++ compiler is `CC`, not `cc` which is the C compiler. Use `CC` with `.cpp` and `cc` with `.c`.

Comment: @hmjd I saw! Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's `CC` for `C++`, not `cc`. So, if you want to compile `C++` in solaris do

```
CC -g -o [output] [filename] [libraries]
```

for `C` do:

```
cc -g -o [output] [filename] [libraries]
```

please pay attention of the upper case letters!

Answer (score 4):

The Solaris (Sun) C++ compiler is `CC` (note capitals). Also note that it tends to be less standards conforming that some other compilers so your code may or may not still compile. You can improve standard library conformance with `-library=stlport4` though.